# How to assign a process to a core in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, multicore

Is there a way to assign a process to a core (or more than one core) on a multi-core system running Windows XP?

An answer using a GUI is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a process's affinity using task manager. Right click on the process in the "Processes" tab, and select "Set Affinity...". The, uncheck all the processors you don't want it to run on.

Answer (score 2):

If you were talking about doing it in code (ala programming) you can utilize the [SetThreadAffinityMask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686247(VS.85).aspx) function

Comment: Know if this is still the current best way in the current framework? This seems like a WinAPI method, and was curious if there is any .NET method to do this easier?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the affility on the application.  [Here is an article that shows you how](http://windows.pradeep.net.in/2007/05/configuring-windows-xp-applications-for.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Curtisk, SetThreadAffinityMask is for a thread, he wanted for a process.  But for a process, it is similar: SetProcessAffinityMask.

Note that the affinity of a thread must reside within the confines of the affinity of its process, or it won't be set at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing. Open the Windows Task manager, right click on the process, and select "set affinity".

Answer (score 0):

TaskManager > Applications > Rt click -  Go to process > Rt click - Set Affinity

Answer (score 0):

In task manager, right click on the process (in the "Processes" view) and choose "Set affinity..."